# How to extract values from a list in Python and put into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have trained a model and have asked the model to produce the coefficients:

```
modelcoeffs = model.fit(X_train, y_train).coef_
coeffslist = list(modelcoeffs)
```

which yiels me for example:

```
print(coeffslist):
[0.17005542 0.72965947 0.6833308  0.02509676]
```

I am trying to split these 4 coefficients out however they dont seem to be individual elements?

does anyone know how to split these into four numbers?

I am trying to get:

```
df['1'] = coeffslist[0]
df['2'] = coeffslist[1]
df['3'] = coeffslist[2]
df['4'] = coeffslist[3]
```

But it gives me `NaN` in the `df`. Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am basically trying to get the coeffs to append to a `df`

```
print(df)

  1             2         3         4    
....         .....      .....      .....
0.17005542 0.72965947 0.6833308  0.02509676
```

Comment: you are adding to a column but not specifying a row where to add

Comment: ah ok, how would i append them all as one row then do you know?

Answer (score 0):

This `coeffslist` doesn't look like a valid Python structure, it's missing commas.

But you might try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0.17005542, 0.72965947, 0.6833308, 0.02509676])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          0
0  0.170055
1  0.729659
2  0.683331
3  0.025097
```

To get the coefs as row try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("1234"))
df.loc[len(df)] = [0.17005542, 0.72965947, 0.6833308, 0.02509676]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          1         2         3         4
0  0.170055  0.729659  0.683331  0.025097
```

And if you want to add another row (append) of coefs, just do this:

```
df.loc[1] = [0.17005542, 0.72965947, 0.6833308, 0.02509676]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          1         2         3         4
0  0.170055  0.729659  0.683331  0.025097
1  0.170055  0.729659  0.683331  0.025097
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, when i ask for `coeffslist[0]` it gives me the correct element but now Im struggling to append those values to the dataframe. See edited question

Answer (score 0):

you can convert [0.17005542 0.72965947 0.6833308  0.02509676] to a sting, split it on space, convert to float again and then append to a dataframe.

```
str_list= str(coeffslist[0])
float_list= [float(x) for x in str_list.split()]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['1','2','3','4'])
a_series = pd.Series(float_list, index = df.columns)
df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```